# Failed to build android app at server - class file for android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found

Tags: android, android-fragments, netbeans, codenameone

My NetBeans recently updated the new CodenameOne plugin module and when I choose "Send Android Build" to build my app. It shows "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" at NetBeans's output window but it was failed at server. I think the main issue on these lines.

```
/tmp/build2245582129963540999xxx/BeautifulPicturePuzzle/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/FacebookImpl.java:108: error: cannot access Fragment
    login.logInWithReadPermissions(activity, permissions);
         ^
class file for android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found
```

Any idea to resolve this? Please let me know if the full log file should be posted.

Thanks,
William

Comment: did you add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'`

Comment: Please guide me how to add this. Thanks!

Comment: You can add additional compile dependencies with 'gradleDependencies' build hint, but support v4 should already be part of the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add build hint android.supportV4=true to your build hints

Answer (score 0):

This is probably failing due to the [switch to gradle](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/video-new-defaults-barcode-qrcode-changes.html) in the build servers.

You should be able to workaround it for now by setting `android.gradle=false` in the build hints.